# Save a raw image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, file-io, opencv

I'm trying to use OpenCV to read/write images for me. Currently, I have them in a different, non-standard format, and I know how to get them into OpenCV's containers. Here are the requirements:

- The pixels are 1, or 3 bands, U8, U16, U32, or F32
- The images have metadata, random stuff, like the camera ID that took the images. I would like the metadata to be vi/notepad editable
- I want to write as little code as possible when it comes to low level stuff. My experience is that this stuff requires the most maintenance.
- I can define the format. It's only to read and write for these programs.
- I don't want the pixels to be anything but binary, '0.5873499082' is way too much data for one float.

Is there a way to describe to OpenCV how to read and write image types it doesn't know? Are there image types already available for the types of images I have?

My interim solution is to use boost to serialize the image, and save the metadata in a separate file.

Comment: I missed the question, what is it again?

Answer (score 0):

Try using gdal library for reading images and then convert it to IplImage.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can't do that for you, you can store the metadata in a separate file, or you can use for example the jpeg exif (that won't be notepad editable though).